# How to stop Google Sheets"The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event" warnings

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, warnings, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to migrate a web app to the new Google Sheets GIS JavaScript API. It's now working with the OAuth popup window and such, but I'm getting these warning messages appear and spam the browser console after waiting a few seconds:

`` docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=xxx:1 The resource https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/js/xxx-waffle_js_prod_integrated_addons.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=xxx:1 The resource https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/js/xxx-waffle_js_prod_integrated_add_ons_app_finder_populator.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=xxx:1 The resource https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/js/xxx-waffle_js_prod_integrated_addons.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=xxx:1 The resource https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/js/xxx-waffle_js_prod_integrated_add_ons_host_content_factory.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=xxx:1 The resource https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/js/xxx-waffle_js_prod_integrated_add_ons_app_finder_populator.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=xxx:1 The resource https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/js/xxx-waffle_js_prod_integrated_add_ons_app_finder_populator.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=xxx:1 The resource https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/js/xxx-waffle_js_prod_integrated_add_ons_host_content_factory.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=xxx:1 The resource https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/js/xxx-waffle_js_prod_integrated_add_ons_promo_bubble_factory.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxx/edit#gid=xxx:1 The resource https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/client/js/xxx-waffle_js_prod_integrated_addons.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. ``

These are on Chrome, sheet/JS URL IDs replaced with xxx. Firefox has a similar, but slightly different warning messages spamming the console.

My Google-fu has failed to dig up anything related to Google Sheets on the warnings. Maybe someone has a clue on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I did some research about the error, could not find much but what I could find is that the warning is making reference to the <link> HTML tag. Can you confirm you're using this tag in your code and share that part of the code to confirm if this is the case?

Comment: Currently using a <link> tag towards a Google font, some material css. Mainly fonts and CSS, but they weren't causing any problems prior to the migration attempt to:

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration

After shifting the code to the new sign-in process, the above spam started happening.